# How does angular provide the arguments mentioned in the component class constructor?

Tags: angular, service

I'm trying to understand angular deeply, so i read [the docs](https://angular.io) and it was very helpful.
now in the dependency injection chapter i read that

> angular uses the injector bubbling technique to provide the service mentioned in the constructor

now the injector bubbling goes to the parent components one by one and check if there is an available instance of the service in order to provide it.

i have two questions:

> Q1) is the arguments in the constructor are always services?
>
> Q2) if there is other than the services is mentioned in the constructor do they also use the bubbling technique?

Comment: _I'm trying to understand angular deeply_ - you mind find [my articles](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi) very insightful

Comment: impressive topics, thanks alot, i register it as an important reference :)

Comment: I write quite often, you might want to follow me on medium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1) is the arguments in the constructor are always services?

If you're talking about classes that are instantiated through injector (for example components) then yes, Angular expects all arguments to the constructor to be injectables.

> Q2) if there is other than the services is mentioned in the
>   constructor do they also use the bubbling technique?

If there's anything else in the constructor that is not defined on any injector you will get an error:

`Cannot resolve all parameters to...`

Answer (score 1):

> is the arguments in the constructor are always services?

No, any configurable value/variable (array, object, string, dynamic runtime string, etc)

> if there is other than the services is mentioned in the constructor do
>   they also use the bubbling technique?

Yes, until the dependency resolver hit the value in the current level injector

Comment: _No, any configurable value/variable_ -  that's misleading, it still should be registered with injector, so it's a service

Comment: _Yes, until the dependency resolver hit t_ - you will have an error as I stated in my answer